# ASP.NET MVC Expression is rendered "as is"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I have the following line:

```
<link href="<%= Links.Content.Site_css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which is rendered to

```
<link href="Views/Shared/%3C%25=%20Links.Content.Site_css%20%25%3E" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So expression is not executed. If I remove quotes:

```
<link href=<%= Links.Content.Site_css %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

expression is executed but markup becomes xhtml incompatible. What is the right way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
<link href='<%= Links.Content.Site_css %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For that special case, I'd use `Css` helper method from MVC futures assembly:

```
<%:Html.Css(Links.Content.Site_css) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the runat="server" on your  tag and it should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a workaround

```
<link href=<%= '"' + Links.Content.Site_css + '"' %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

(I have no experience with ASP, sorry if that's just invalid syntax)